# Java Recursion Over A Text File

Tags: java, file-io, recursion

I have a text file that represents a building. A building has floors, and floors have rooms.

The first floor is floor 0.

The text file is structured like so:

```
Description
Image
North
East
South
West
Up
Down
```

Where North, East, South, West, Up and Down are integers denoting the room that direction leads to. The integer -1 is used to denote that there is no exit in that direction.

This is repeated for the number of rooms the building has.

So for four rooms the contents of the text file may be:

```
this is room 0
somefilepath
1
-1
-1
-1
2
-1
this is room 1
somefilepath
-1
-1
-1
0
-1
-1
this is room 2
somefilepath
-1
-1
-1
-1
3
0
this is room 3
somefilepath
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
2
```

I'm trying to write a recursive function that will allow me to calculate the number of floors in the building based on the up values. For example, if we have a room that goes up to room 1, and room 1 goes up to room 2 and that no other rooms go higher than this then we know that there are 3 floors.

I know how to use either a BufferedReader or Scanner object to read the text file but the recursion is what I'm concerned about.

I want to say thank-you in advance, the community here is amazing.

My method to calculate the number of floors (incomplete and may be wrong):

```
public int calculateFloors(int previousUp, int currentRoom) {
    Scanner scanner;
    int total = 0;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(currentMap);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
            scanner.nextLine();
            int up = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            scanner.nextLine();
            if (up > 0) {
                // do something
                if (currentRoom == previousUp) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
            currentRoom++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total;   
}
```

Comment: Standard question: what have you tried? What part are you having trouble with? Do you have some code that shows what you have in mind and in what way it's not working?

Comment: @vanza I've posted my method so far, as you can see I'm not really sure how to implement the recursion.

Comment: The definition of recursion is a method that is defined in terms of itself. In terms of programming, it's a method that calls itself. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-recursion-in-java-programming.html

Comment: @James thanks for the link, I am aware that I need to call the function within itself, that's why I have those two parameters to keep track of values. I'm just not really sure how to apply it to this situation.

Comment: personally i don't think a recursive method is required...

Comment: @James how so? I would much prefer an iterative approach if you know of one.

Comment: Question: what does the up integer represent? in the first instance it's 2, does that mean up to floor 2?

Comment: @James yes it does and as you can see floor 2 can go back down to floor 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I edited my idea:

So what we need to do: 
We visit each room and follow all possible ways from that room. If we go up we add +1, if we go down we substract -1 and if we stay on the same level we dont add a value.
Also we need to keep track for the rooms already visited to not go in cycles.

```
public int calculateFloors(int current, Set<Integer> visited) {
    int floors = 0;

    // get the values of the directions (add your code here to get them)
    int north = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 
    int east = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 
    int west = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 
    int south = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 
    int down = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 
    int up = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()); 


    if (up > 0 && !visited.contains(up)) {
        visited.add(up);
        floors = calculateFloors(up, visited) + 1;
    }

    if (down > 0 && !visited.contains(down)) {
        visited.add(down);
        int result = calculateFloors(down, visited) - 1;
        floors = result > floors ? result : floors;
    }

    if (north > 0 && !visited.contains(north)) {
        visited.add(north);
        int result = calculateFloors(norht, visited);
        floors = result > floors ? result : floors;
    }

    if (south > 0 && !visited.contains(south)) {
        visited.add(south);
        int result = calculateFloors(south, visited);
        floors = result > floors ? result : floors;
    }
    if (west > 0 && !visited.contains(west)) {
        visited.add(west);
        int result = calculateFloors(west, visited);
        floors = result > floors ? result : floors;
    }
    if (east > 0 && !visited.contains(east)) {
        visited.add(east);
        int result = calculateFloors(east, visited);
        floors = result > floors ? result : floors;
    }


    return floors;
}
```

This should work (just add the code to find the directions values of the current room) in my opinioin.

Comment: Where's the base case?

Comment: It seems to go on indefinitely

Comment: i havent tested this, it's just how I would do it. But it should terminate when there is no more floor up, i.e. when `up` equals -1

Comment: @Edgar, but this has to be done for each and every room, cause you are not checking if there is a way up form an adjacent room/s.

Comment: ok now i understood the whole problematic here. Let me think about it

Comment: Am I calling it correctly? calculateFloors(0, new HashSet<Integer>());

Comment: yes that should be fine, if all rooms are connected, that should calculate it. Are you sure you are getting the direction values correctly? maybe add a syso to check them.

Comment: @Edgar,I was being stupid and kept re-instantiating the Scanner each time due to the recursion. Working now. Very nice solution in my opinion.

Comment: glad it works now :) Just one thing: I think it returns one less floor, so you should add 1 to the result.

Comment: @Edgar it seems to return the correct amount without the addition :s

Comment: @Edgar, do you think there is a way I can keep track of the rooms and put them in each of there floors where a floor is a 2D array?

Comment: @Ciphor Hmm this here would be the easiest way: for each floor you have saved the number of floors above it in `floors`. So all you would need to do, is before `return floors;` save the value of it in your array or a map (current room -> number of floors above). And when the function has finished, you could go through your array/map, and substract each element from the actual number of floors to get the real floor number of the rooms. Hope this was understandable xD

Comment: I think I get what you mean but I don't think that would preserve the layout of the floor would it? For instance a floor is a 2D array which we can treat as row and columns. Room 0 can be in the center of the 2D array and then we build the rooms around it? For example the first floor might look like this - http://puu.sh/5rQiF.png

Comment: Ah ok now I understand. What you could do is add two parameters to the function, `x` and `y`. When you call the function recursively you just provide the correct x and y values. For example for the North case: `calculateFloors(north, visited, x, y+1)`. At the end of the function you just save the current room in the array using x and y. In fact, you could also add a third parameter for the current floor in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int calculateFloors(int count) {
    Scanner scanner;
    int count=1;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(currentMap);
        //uses count to work out what rooms we can skip 
        for(int i=0;i<count*6)
            scanner.nextLine();
        //gets the value of up
        int up = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        //our base case --- if there are no more floors, return the number --- otherwise perform the recursive call.
        if(up==-1)
            return count;
        else
            count+=calculateFloors(count++);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return count;   
}
```

Try that.

Comment: My logic is wrong for skipping the rooms, but that's something you can fine tune

Comment: Updated the post to work as i expected it to, missed one ++ operator ;)

Comment: Also you can't have the parameter count as well as the local variable count. Which one is which? Also your for loop is missing the third part where you increment i. And I'm pretty sure you don't want to be multiplying count by 6. It will always just be 6 :)

Comment: Lol me being stupid can't refine without the files, get rid of int count = 1! When you call the method, just pass in a parameter of 1. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Depth-First-Search over the rooms (you do not need a recursive function). You might go up and down to reach the top.

```
public static class Room {
  public final int[] neighborsSameFloor; // indices of the rooms on the same floor
  public final int neighborUp; // index of the room above
  public final int neighborDown; // index of the room below
  public Room(/*???*/) {
    // do the initialisation
  }
}

public Room[] readRooms() {
  // read file here
}

public int getEntry() {
  // returns the first room to enter
}

public int calculateFloorCount() {
  Room[] rooms = readRooms();
  int currentRoomIndex = getEntry();
  int minFloor = 0;
  int maxFloor = 0;
  int roomFloors[] = new int[rooms.length];
  boolean[] visited = new boolean[rooms.length];
  Stack<Integer> roomStack = new Stack<>();
  roomStack.push(currentRoomIndex);
  // roomFloors[currentRoom] = 0;
  // Arrays.fill(visted, false); both should happen automatically when the arrays are initialized

  while (!roomStack.empty()) {
    currentRoomIndex = roomStack.pop();
    // ignore already visited rooms
    if (visited[currentRoomIndex]) continue;
    visited[currentRoomIndex] = true;
    Room room = rooms[currentRoomIndex];
    int currentFloor = roomFloors[currentRoomIndex];

    if (currentFloor > maxFloor)
      maxFloor = currentFloor;
    else if (currentFloor < minFloor)
      minFloor = currentFloor;

    // add room one floor up
    if (room.neighborUp >= 0 && !visited[room.neighborUp]) {
      roomFloors[room.neighborUp] = currentFloor+1;
      roomStack.push(room.neighborUp);
    }

    // add room one floor down
    if (room.neighborDown >= 0 && !visited[room.neighborDown]) {
      roomFloors[room.neighborDown] = currentFloor-1;
      roomStack.push(room.neighborDown);
    }

    // add rooms on the same floor
    for (int i = 0; i < room.neighborsSameFloor.length; i++) {
      int index = room.neighborsSameFloor[i];
      roomFloors[index] = currentFloor;
      roomStack.push(index);
    }
  }

  return maxFloor-minFloor+1;
}
```